# Send a JavaScript object to Apex using lightning

Tags: apex, lightning

Is it possible to send a JavaScript object to Apex without using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.deserialize`?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
class A {
    class B {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String str;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void doesNotMatter(B b) {
        //does not matter
    }
}
```

And here is what I am doing in lightning:

```
const action = component.get("c.doesNotMatter");
action.setParams({ b: { str: "hello" } });
action.setCallback(component, function() {
        const state = response.getState();
        if(state === "SUCCESS") {

        } else {
            console.log("Something is wrong");
        }
});
$A.getCallback(function(){$A.enqueueAction(action);})();
```

And here is a response which I am getting:

[image]

`"An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1665868370-341185 (545702440)"`.

What am I missing here? Or maybe it is actually impossible to achieve what I want?

Also when I tried to change the apex to this:

```
public static void doesNotMatter(B b) {
    System.debug('b: ' + b);
}
```

No output was produced in the logs.

The reason I hope this to work is because it works with objects (there instead of a class `B` an object class is used, e.g. `Contact` or `Account`).

Thank you.

Comment: `component.get("doesNotMatter")` should be `component.get("c.doesNotMatter")` - is that just an artifact of extracting code for this post, though?

Comment: @DavidReed, it is just an artifact, let me update, please.

Comment: Try with quoting the key property of JSON as in standard JavaScript key should not be unquoted: { 'b': { 'str': "hello" } }

Comment: @Raul that's not necessary for JavaScript, only JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just send it as MAP?, JSON is basically a map so  it can just accept any Sobject, or any Object.

```
public static void doesNotMatter(Map<Object,Object> jsonMap) {

   System.debug(jsonMap);
}
```

JS:

```
({
    doesNotMatter: function(component, event, helper) {
        let action = component.get("c.doesNotMatter");
        action.setParams({ jsonMap:  component.get("v.acc")}); //Can be any Object except list
        action.setCallback(component, function(response) {
            const state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {

            } else {
                console.log("Something is wrong");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I would prefer to figure out what is wrong in my approach over resorting to your solution since my approach seems to be cleaner for me.

Comment: if my understanding is correct, the recommended approach is to actually send a  Map -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_object.htm